# Django REST framework absolute urls with nginx always return 127.0.0.1

Tags: python, django, rest, nginx

I've an app running on gunicorn / django (with django-rest-framework) behind nginx and I've a little problem with the url return by the rest framework when using the `hyperlinkedmodelserializer`. They always return something like `http://127.0.0.1/` instead of my host name.

Could you help please ?

Comment: What does your `settings.py` file look like?

Comment: Hello, I've found out the issue - the nginx configuration was wrong - I wasn't setting proxy_set_header Host $host; nor proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;. From what I've found in the code about absolute url generation, django can use both of those.

Answer (score 10):

Never mind, I've found I've forgot to put

```
proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

in my nginx config. Works fine now.